# How to debug "Could not load file or assembly" runtime errors?

Tags: c#, .net, load, runtime, ikvm

I have a project that uses a Java library converted using [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/). I added the created DLL plus all possible IKVM DLLs as references to my project, but when I run it, I get the following runtime error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'core, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I'm not really sure how to debug this error. Is there a way to know exactly which type is missing? From the description I'd guess this is the generated DLL (from the Java lib) but I have properly added it as reference.

What else have I done wrong?

Comment: As I am not sure so I won't submit a answer. A missing .DLL won't throw a IOexception. More likely does the .DLL read some sort of file ( a config or something ) and it's missing. You should probably check the manual for this IKVM.

Comment: The "assembly" tag is for assembly language programming. I have deleted it, hope you don't mind.

Comment: Great idea, but I think you forgot to add the ikvm tag which is best for this post ;)

Comment: Finally, the missing DLL was the generated one, as I suspected. I was supposed to be name core.dll (and nothing else), so I just renamed it and voilà !

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the [Fusion Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.71).aspx) to debug assembly loading problems in .NET apps.

Also, [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) is very useful in identifying general file-load problems.

Comment: A better (in my opinion) version of Fusion Log Viewer has been developed here: https://github.com/awaescher/Fusion

Answer (score 9):

Just chiming in that dependency walker and fusion log viewer dont work well for applications that have native and managed code together or doing dynamic loading of native code. Here is a good post explaining step by step how to solve missing (or invalid permission) assembly errors using process monitor that covers those scenarios:

[Debug Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies error with Process Monitor](https://web.archive.org/web/20130328034650/http://tech.blinemedical.com/debug-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies/)

The post also includes a tool to automate some of this task as well

Answer (score 6):

You can diagnose that by using Fusion Log Viewer (available in the Microsoft SDK).
Launch it in Administrator and activate the log in the Settings.

It will log all the informations regarding your references loading (and all their references).
It will explicitly tell you which reference is missing and where it has searched for it.

[MSDN on Fusion Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

There is a program called [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) which allows you to see the dependencies of a given PE file (dll, exe, ocx...).

This error is really annoying, very difficult to debug. You have to make sure that your dll is present as well as *ANY dependency this dll has*. This keypoint is usually where the headache kicks in.

Comment: Dependency walker will resolve native dependencies. This looks like a managed dependency issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using [ProcessMonitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) (from the Sysinternals Suite), you could see which DLL your process is looking for right before the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

The dependency walker statically resolves all the DLLs needed by a native PE file and flags missing dependencies, while Fusion Log Viewer catches assembly binding problems in managed code during runtime. For managed .Net code that loads native DLLs dynamically these tools are not enough.

Here is a blog post on how you can use Process Monitor to debug “Could not load file or assembly” problems: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/560816/Troubleshooting-dependency-resolution-problems-usi