# .NET Web Deployment project giving error "The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference"

Tags: asp.net, c#-2.0, tridion, web-deployment

I am using .net 2.0, visual studio 2008, In my solution I have two projects (website project and references project), I build both of them seperately theya re build successfully, however when I am trying to built the solution using web deployment project it is giving below error, what can be the cause of this issue?

> Error 2   Could not load file or assembly 'Tridion.Extensions.Web.UI, Version=1.0.0.19738, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7c1e07388cce59cc' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)   /Careers/Controls/Application/ucBreadcrumbs.ascx    2   1   Careers_deploy

Please suggest!!

Comment: Is the version of `Tridion.Extensions.Web.UI` in your bin directory actually `1.0.0.19738`?

Comment: Actually my website and reference project are building successfully with this dll, however when I trying to use web deployment project and building that then I am getting abolve error...please suggest

Comment: Sorry, I have next-to-no experience of web deployment projects... all I can *guess* is making sure that all your references within the project are as you're expecting (I know that's vague, but it's as good as I can suggest)

Comment: How are you referencing the project?

Comment: "Tridion.Extensions.Web.UI" is not a standard Tridion assembly, so I guess you should try hunting down this assembly's creator and trying to figure out what it needs? You might have upgraded Tridion and this assembly was compiled against an older version of the Tridion assemblies - you may need to recompile it.

Comment: Nuno...you are right this is not tridion standard DLL as this is working as wrapper using the Tridion provided DLLs....the probleme is that same DLLs is working fine in other application and we are able to build the application using web deployment.

Comment: We have recompiled the old dlls using Tridion 2011 Dlls and same DLLs are working fine on other application, really something is missed out here and causing pain...any suggestions

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest looking into .NET's assembly loading mechanism (http://stackoverflow.com/q/4602912/209103), since it may well be that a dependency is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have policy files on those working systems which makes sure it loads the right version.

Anyway, your best option for troubleshooting is to run Fusion Log Viewer. Log the failures and look through the reports. Most of the time, this is enough to tell you exactly what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Peter is right - fuslogvw is very useful for this kind of problem.

In addition to that, I'd suggest that an important phrase in that error message is "`or one of its dependencies`". I'd suggest opening up the `Tridion.Extensions.Web.UI` assembly with a tool that allows you to see its dependencies in the manifest. ILDASM is perfectly good for this. Equipped with the knowledge you find here, you can ensure that the other necessary assemblies are available. (It's not uncommon to find that on the system where things work, a necessary assembly is present in the GAC, while on a system where it doesn't work, it isn't.)

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your solution, and see if that works.

If it doesn't try deleting the temporary ASP.NET folder which should follow a path like this:

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET

Comment: I am referencing DLLs in website bin directory, i clean the solution and cleaned the temporary files but no luck...any suggestions

Comment: Did you manually add the dll to the bin folder or reference it by right clicking on References->Add Reference?

Comment: Yes I used right clicking on References->Add Reference, its really frustrating as everything is building up perfectcly, however when trying to build the project using web deployment project, its getting failed...please suggest any possibilities

Comment: Hmm, try: right click on the reference-> properties and set Copy Local to true. Where are deploying too? a shared server maybe?

Comment: which references-> properties? see I have to projects and one web deployment project in my solution, the DLLs which is causing the issue is in Website bin directory and as I have told seperatley builing is successfully, the problem is coming only when building the project using web deployment project...do we need to some changes in "Prooerty pages"...please suggest!!

Comment: Right click on the reference 'Tridion.Extensions.Web.UI' (inside the References folder) go to properties and set 'Copy local' to true. Are you deploying to a shared server?

Comment: Before doing that it is important to realize that this means you will be overwriting that DLL in the deployment target with the one your Visual Studio project references. Given the error message about conflicting version, you might well end up deploying the wrong version to a production server.