# Identifying assembly causing 'type not found' error

Tags: c#

I am getting an error.

Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

I can see the type that cannot be loaded, but how do I find out which assembly has a problem?

Comment: I have verified that CopyLocal is true on my assemblies

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602912/how-to-debug-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-runtime-errors