# Could not load type 'Rotativa.ActionAsPdf'

Tags: c#, .net, rotativa

> Could not load type 'Rotativa.ActionAsPdf' from assembly 'Rotativa,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'Rotativa.ActionAsPdf' from assembly 'Rotativa, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

I started a new mvc 5 project, added rotativa via nuget using the following command:

Install-Package Rotativa

I am very depressed can somebody please help me.

Comment: "Could not load type" is just the conclusion of a failed assembly load. You need to analyze everything that happens before there. See [How to debug “Could not load file or assembly” runtime errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602912/how-to-debug-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-runtime-errors).

Answer (score 0):

DLL hell is a pain.

Check that the DLLs referenced are present in the correct location. Check that the versions of the DLLs are the same as the ones you have added to your project. Check that the dependencies the DLLs are all present. Check that the references in your project are correct.  think Rotativa also needs to be loaded into your project as well.

Check the below link:

[C#: Could not load types from assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297961/c-could-not-load-types-from-assembly)